# Fiddler - Change HTTP Request Header

Tags: wcf, fiddler

I wish to create a HTTP  **request** header using Fiddler.

I have a Service running which exposes a Method, which has an object parameter. The object looks like this:

```
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Details { get; set; }
    ....
```

Does anyone know how I can populate these objects and send them to my WCFServices? I am using localhost.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to change the HTTP headers? If so, the code shown isn't relevant. What exactly do you want to change and why? See [here](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp) for a few samples on using scripting in Fiddler. If it's really the XML request message you want to alter, I can advise looking into [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Comment: Edited my post. Please re-read it.

Comment: FWIW, it is also possible to [modify a request or response in-flight](http://web.archive.org/web/20190627153139/https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) before it is sent to the server, resp. application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by:

Opening Fiddler, clicking on Composer, adding:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` In the Parsed tab.

And Key pair values in the Request Body, e.g:

```
{
   "Name" : "Arnold",
   "Data" : "SomeDataHere"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how I can populate these objects

Take a look at [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) or at the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx).